# How to sort the files based on the grep count?

Tags: grep

my grep -c command for a particular pattern returns files as follows

```
A:2
B:6
c:1
d:9
```

Now i want to sort the files based on this command. so my final op will be

```
c:1
A:2
B:6
d:9
```

how to use grep and sort together?

Comment: For some reason I can't edit this question. It needs to show the output as a column, not a row.

Answer (score 8):

`grep -c <pattern> * | sort -n -k2 -t:`

The `-k2` changes the key field, the `-t:` sets the field separator to `:` (the `-n` means a numeric sort)

Comment: In case somebody needs the file with most occurrences first: add `-r` for reverse order: `grep -c <pattern> * | sort -n -r -k2 -t:`

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
grep -c $pattern A B c d | sort -n -t: -k2
```

`-n` means numeric sort, `-t:` means that the column delimiter is `:` and `-k2` means that the second column is considered for sorting.